# Did Facebook changed its GRAPH API?

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api, curl

I built a curl script to post on fb pages a month ago; it was working fine as of today (30/04/2015) but the behaviour has changed. Earlier it was posting as the page on its feed but today it is posting as me, not as the page on its feed.

Has Facebook made any changes in its API that could have caused this?

NB:
I have extended my access token by using below code and have debugged it, as publish_action, publish_page, user_user_status access too

```
https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token?client_id=XX& client_secret=XZ&grant_type=fb_exchange_token&fb_exchange_token=XXX
```

Comment: Are you using a user access token or a page access token? You have to use a page access token

Comment: hi Wizkid ,
thanks for your reply,
Regarding page access token I don't know in much detail as I am new to this API.
I have followed the below steps to generate my access token.
1. created a new app on developers.facebook.com
2. went to graph explorer & generated a access token with publish_action, publish_pages, user_user_status access.
3.Extended the access token for two months.


It was working fine till yesterday night but today it posting as me on the facebook page feed.

Comment: Sounds like a bug if it worked before. Follow the instructions at https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/access-tokens on how to get a page access token

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's clearly stated in the docs at https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.3/page/feed/#pubperms that you need to use a Page Access Token if you want to post as Page:

> A page access token with publish_pages permission can be used to publish new posts on behalf of that page. Posts will appear in the voice of the page.

Remember, today is the day that Graph API v1.0 gets deprecated!

Have a look at

- https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/access-tokens#pagetokens

on how to get a Page Access Token.

Comment: hi tobi thanks for your reply, 

Regarding page access token I don't know in much detail as I am new to this API.
I have followed the below steps to generate my access token.
1. created a new app on developers.facebook.com
2. went to graph explorer & generated a access token with publish_action, publish_pages, user_user_status access.
3.Extended the access token for two months.


It was working fine till yesterday night but today it posting as me on the facebook page feed.

Answer (score 0):

For me it was combination of both of the things. Now the facebook has fixed his bug, I have given manage_page rights to my app & my code starts working again.
Thank you all responding

Answer (score -1):

For us our API suddenly stop working this morning and after almost 12 hrs of debugging we found that facebook has introduced a bug (which itself was a surprise to me)

Now waiting for fix to come
https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/380833342117530/